# Sentiment analysis social media with Naive Bayes

Tags: twitter, classification, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to implement sentiment analysis on Google+ posts using a Naive Bayes classification.

I have been looking for a dataset, and the only one I found was made for twitter. A google+ post and tweet have a lot in common but maybe not the **length**. **I'd like to know if that changes anything for a NB classification.**

Also Naive Bayes takes **smileys** into account but suppose **we want to give them more weight in text** (since they express unambiguously the emotion of a tweet). Is there a way to do that with naive bayes?

Comment: Assuming you're doing it on the "post" level, shorter posts might be easier to learn from and classify since they tend to be more straightforward in expression opinions, but the only way to find out is  to do experiments, possibly with the same feature set and different ones. For weight of emoticons, if they're truly unambiguous or more "determinative" than other features, it will be reflected through learning by the conditional probabilities of it being true given the corresponding label assuming the emoticons are one of the features.

Comment: You may also want to try logistic regression and svms as they tend to give better results than nb.

Comment: on your sentiment analysis, are you just trying to classify it in two categories say positive sentiments and negative, or you are trying to give score too? For eg: -0.8 for highly negative sentiment and 0.5 for moderately positive sentiments? 

Besides, twitter texts are shorter and they only give a single sentiment per tweet (except few ones) but in google+ posts, single post can contain mixture of sentiment including both positive and negative and even facts. Are you doing a sentence level classification or post level?